# How to import django models in scrapy pipelines.py file

Tags: python, django, models, scrapy

I'm trying to import models of one django application in my pipelines.py to save data using django orm. I created a scrapy project scrapy_project in the first involved django application "app1" (is it a good choice by the way?).
I added these lines to my scrapy settings file:

```
def setup_django_env(path):
  import imp, os
  from django.core.management import setup_environ

  f, filename, desc = imp.find_module('settings', [path])
  project = imp.load_module('settings', f, filename, desc)

  setup_environ(project)

current_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
setup_django_env(os.path.join(current_dir, '../../d_project1'))
```

When I try to import models of my django application app1 I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 76, in     _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 129, in     _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in     run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/command.py", line 33, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 41, in configure
    self.engine = ExecutionEngine(self, self._spider_closed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 63, in     __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 66, in     __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 50, in     from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 29, in     from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 39, in     load_object
    raise ImportError, "Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)
ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy_project.pipelines.storage.storage': No module         named dydict.models
```

Why cannot scrapy access django application models (given that app1 in the installed_app ) ?

Comment: you just need to get the correct path so that you can access the model

Comment: What do you mean? are you talking about setup_django_env? if so, the only path allowed is the django project directory where lives the settings file. In my piplines I'm supposed to import models like that I guess: form app1 import models. Right?

Comment: from app1.models import ......

Comment: That's exactly what I did :), why don't it recognize dydict as application? or why don't it see dydict?

Comment: did you install it in your installed app? put sample codes

Comment: how did you call the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from .. models import MyModel
```

**OR**

```
from ... models import MyModel
```

Every dot represent the location

Comment: It's really so weird and I don't understand. Why is it so difficult!!
Does not work, all what I can import is the models file in the project directory of django. I even created a scrapy project on the same level Hierarchical as django applications, and I wasn't able to import my apps models.

Comment: Because you put scrapy project inside dydict app

Comment: I even created a scrapy project on the same Hierarchical level as django applications, and I wasn't able to import my apps models (ditto :'( ).

Answer (score 1):

In the pipelines you don't import django models, you use scrapy models bounded to a django model.
You have to add Django Settings at scrapy settings, not after.

To use django models in scrapy project you have to use django_Item
https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-djangoitem (import to your pythonpath)

My recommended file structure is:

```
Projects
 |-DjangoScrapy
     |-DjangoProject
     |     |-Djangoproject
     |     |-DjangoAPP
     |-ScrapyProject
            |-ScrapyProject
                 |-Spiders
```

Then in your scrapy project you hace to **add pythonpath ull path to the django project**:

```
**# Setting up django's project full path.**
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/PycharmProject/scrap/DjangoProject')

# Setting up django's settings module name.
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'DjangoProject.settings'
```

Then in your items.py you cand bound your Django models to scrapy models:

```
from DjangoProject.models import Person, Job
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem

class Person(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Person
class Job(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Job
```

Then u can use the .save() method in pipelines after yeld of an object:

**spider.py**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from mybot.items import PersonItem

class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.dmoz.org/World/Espa%C3%B1ol/Artes/Artesan%C3%ADa/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # do stuff
        return PersonItem(name='zartch')
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from myapp.models import Person

class MybotPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        obj = Person.objects.get_or_create(name=item['name'])
        return obj
```

I have a repository with the minimal code working: (you just have to set the path of your django project in scrapy settings)
https://github.com/Zartch/Scrapy-Django-Minimal

in:
https://github.com/Zartch/Scrapy-Django-Minimal/blob/master/mybot/mybot/settings.py
You have to change my Django Project path to your DjangoProject path:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/zartch/PycharmProjects/Scrapy-Django-Minimal/myweb')
```