# Best practices: where to put a scraping file in django framework

Tags: python, django

I have a scraping script that has to run once in a while (maybe once per day). This script populates a database using django models. There is no url or view calling the script (at the moment), so I would consider it a static file and put it under myapp/static/myapp/scraping/scraping.py. 
Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using scrapy with django. 

https://blog.theodo.com/2019/01/data-scraping-scrapy-django-integration/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321584/how-to-import-django-models-in-scrapy-pipelines-py-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) is the perfect place for this kind of script